# Android Facebook-SDK multipart/form-data upload got "Invalid OAuth access token"

Tags: android, upload, multipart, facebook

I use HttpCilent 4.0.1 to upload picture, but I got HTTP 400 Error, the error message like this, Plz someone help me.

> {"error":{"type":"OAuthException","message":"Invalid
>   OAuth access token."}}

My code is...

```
private void uploadPicture( ) throws ParseException, IOException {
    HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
    httpclient.getParams( ).setParameter( CoreProtocolPNames.PROTOCOL_VERSION, HttpVersion.HTTP_1_1 );

    HttpPost httppost = new HttpPost( "https://graph.facebook.com/me/photos" );
    File file = new File( sdpicturePath );

    // DEBUG
    Log.d( "TSET", "FILE::" + file.exists( ) ); // IT IS NOT NULL
    Log.d( "TEST", "AT:" + fbAccessToken ); // I GOT SOME ACCESS TOKEN

    MultipartEntity mpEntity  = new MultipartEntity( );
    ContentBody cbFile        = new FileBody( file, "image/png" );
    ContentBody cbMessage     = new StringBody( "TEST TSET" );
    ContentBody cbAccessToken = new StringBody( fbAccessToken );

    mpEntity.addPart( "access_token", cbAccessToken );
    mpEntity.addPart( "source",       cbFile        );
    mpEntity.addPart( "message",      cbMessage     );        

    httppost.setEntity( mpEntity );

    // DEBUG
    System.out.println( "executing request " + httppost.getRequestLine( ) );
    HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute( httppost );
    HttpEntity resEntity = response.getEntity( );

    // DEBUG
    System.out.println( response.getStatusLine( ) );
    if (resEntity != null) {
      System.out.println( EntityUtils.toString( resEntity ) );
    } // end if

    if (resEntity != null) {
      resEntity.consumeContent( );
    } // end if

    httpclient.getConnectionManager( ).shutdown( );
} // end of uploadPicture( )
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The access token you receive needs to be URL Decoded. I used URLDecoder.decode() with MultiPartEntity(HttpMultipartMode.STRICT);